# Printing the letters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, reactjs, canvasjs

I'm new to Javascript part, i'm trying to print the letters over the Y axis based on X axis position. Basically this is for printing the market profile.

My output will be like below image.

[image]

To achieve this, i have data but i'm not getting how we can do it via Javascript. i tried googling and found this JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/901L4pvn/
here is the code.

```
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    axisY: {
    gridThickness: 0
  },
  data: [
    {
      type: "scatter",
      color: "transparent",
      toolTipContent: null,
      indexLabel: "{text}",
      dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 71, text: "Data 1" },
        { x: 20, y: 55, text: "Data 2" },
        { x: 30, y: 50, text: "Data 3" },
        { x: 40, y: 65, text: "Data 4" },
        { x: 50, y: 95, text: "Data 5" },
        { x: 60, y: 68, text: "Data 6" },
        { x: 70, y: 28, text: "Data 7" },
        { x: 80, y: 34, text: "Data 8" },
        { x: 90, y: 14, text: "Data 9" }
      ]
    }                   
  ]
});
```

looking for some more options or any other sample script which is similar to my requirement is available?. Even if the script is in React.js or Angular.js is also ok.

Comment: Your code bears little resemblance to the desired output. What letters are you referring to?

Comment: I want to print the letters present in the excel sheet image which i have attached,is there a way we can achieve?. i'm looking for any sample code or example project. The sample code which i have pasted is found in google, but it might not suite.